# How to include github project in iOS app just like dependancy in android studio

Tags: ios, swift, github, git-clone

I tried xcode->  Source Control -> Checkout -> In Respository Location ("https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid.git") -> Download

The github project got downloaded to my project folder, but i am not able to use any classes of it. I am an android app developer, aware of dependancies in android, i'm very new to iOS app development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html). It will tell you how to use "pods" in your project.

Comment: Using pod installation.

Comment: Look at the Installation instructions of the git repository: It tells you to install it using CocoaPods. That's the most common package/dependency manager used for iOS. Check the CocoaPods page for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods is a popular way to many dependencies. Simple as adding pod "GlyuckDataGrid" to a podfile and running pod install. Instructions for installing are here: https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install Cocoa pod on your Mac system by running following command on Terminal

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Then after simply download the code from the github : https://github.com/glyuck/GlyuckDataGrid.git

After that, Go to the project directory where is PodFile.
and simply run following command.

```
Pod install
```

then all dependency and missing file automatically download.
Now you have to open project by the workSpace in xcode.